# How do I reference specific child objects in OnTriggerEnter2D

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I'm currently trying to check if child objects, whose parent is running the script, are colliding with things. It doesn't matter what they're colliding with on the layer, I just want to know which of the child objects is colliding with something.

The general idea is that I have one child object on each side of the parent so I can detect collision for specific sides of the parent. I'm using OnTriggerEnter2D without issue to detect collision of *any* of the child objects, and I'm assuming I should be using a basic 'if' statement to specify further, but I'm not exactly sure what I should be doing beyond that.

I'm not quite sure how to efficiently search for this on google or in the Unity Documentation, though I tried, so I thought I'd ask here.

/edit

So, as per the advice I received, I tried using scripts in the child objects. I'm having some issues while testing. Unity is throwing an error at me whenever OnTriggerEnted2D is called from the child script; "Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CheckCollision.OnTriggerEnter2D."

I'm still new to Unity and C#, so I've been working at this mainly from public documentation. As such, the error is probably something obvious to anyone with more experience.

Side note: I also attempted Nikass' suggestion of using relative position for the parent compared to detection, messing with InverseTransformPoint, but quickly got confused. I'm also not even sure if that's the right direction to go. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Here's the relevant code:

Main Script:

```
public bool isColliding;

void Start()
{
    isColliding = false;
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    Debug.Log("Collided with" + col.name);
}
```

Child Script:

```
    public GameObject player;

public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D checkCol)
{
    player.GetComponent<PlayerGridMovement>().isColliding = true;
    print(GetComponent<PlayerGridMovement>().isColliding);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the OnTrigger script on each of the 4 child objects?

Comment: Another idea depending on how child triggers are positioned (may or may not be viable) is OnTrigger to check the difference in position between this parent object, i.e. if the object that has entered is left/righ/etc. and how far compared to the partent.

Comment: What I've currently been doing is having a 2dcollider placed on each child object and trying to create public gameobjects within the parent to reference the component. I'm unfamiliar with the syntax, in this case, assuming that this is how it would be done.
I have not tried putting a script on the child objects, as that seemed unnecessarily complex to me, but I may give that a shot.

Comment: I've updated the original question to suit my attempts to follow your suggestions.